# Can Le Creuset Dutch Oven be used in the microwave in convection mode?

Tags: baking, cast-iron, microwave, dutch-oven, convection

I am reading that cast iron may pop or crackle in a convection oven, and aluminum is best for it. Since Le Creuset Dutch Oven is just enameled cast iron, I couldn't help but have a safety concern over using it in the microwave's convection mode.

Comment: Where are you reading "pop and crackle" be what do you mean by it?

Comment: Pop or crackle? That's complete baloney. Microwaving cast iron is a bad idea, but a convection oven is fine.

Comment: @GdD I see two possibilities: the source was talking about microwaving and being confusing; or the plastic knobs on some models being affected by intense direct heat.  You wouldn't grill/broil with the lid on anyway, but the knob couldn't take it if you did ([max 250°C](https://www.lecreuset.co.uk/en_GB/p/signature-phenolic-knob/CI94032.html))

Comment: I suspect it's about microwaving @ChrisH, the temperature in a convection oven doesn't get hotter than a conventional, non-fan oven so I can't see knobs being a problem. Le Creuset knobs are indestructible as far as I can tell.

Comment: @GdD the air temperature  doesn't get hotter, but a black piece of plastic subjected to the halogen element at close range would.  Infrared absorption can get things stupidly hot.  But I agree that the fear is probably based on microwaving, which would obviously have food safety implications too, as the microwaves won't penetrate inside the dish

Comment: @ChrisH I should have been more specific about where I read it from-it was from a forum where users can post and the post I read it in wasn't even upvoted much:

https://qr.ae/pGLl2C

Comment: Ignore that Quora post. It makes a fundamental error in assuming that a convection oven is the same thing as a microwave.  Then it  assumes that the failure mode of putting a big metal thing in a microwave is an explosion (a few sparks are likely, maybe confusing the electronics, but not an explosion you'd need to stand back from). It's nonsense from beginning to end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le Creuset and convection ovens work well together.

One issue may be that some microwave ovens turn on the microwave part even in convection mode. More honest ones call this combination mode, and have a separate convection mode (like mine).

There are a couple of potential issues even with decent convection microwaves. One is that it will take a long time to heat through in a fairly weak oven. Another is that it's likely to be quite tricky to get a full size one in.

If you're using it with the lid on (if it even fits), the lid will come very close to the element. That's where the biggest issue arises, because the (oven-proof plastic) knob on the lid can't take that much direct heat. In some models the (top) element is far enough back that it won't directly heat the knob. In others I wouldn't trust it not to damage the plastic.

Comment: I thought only the models with a metal knob were oven-proof (I mean the lid, the vessels obviously are)

Comment: @Luciano the plastic knobs are definitely oven proof up to a point.  Mine was fine for years but suffered cosmetically when I used it for baking bread at 240°C (twice a week for most of 2020) and I've seen similar effects when they're used in an Aga

Comment: @Luciano found it:  [max 250°C](https://www.lecreuset.co.uk/en_GB/p/signature-phenolic-knob/CI94032.html)

Comment: So I checked the microwave I am going to use and it explicitly mentions Convection as one option and Micro-Convection as another option.

Regarding the knob on the top of the lid of my Le Creuset Dutch Oven, as far as I can see it's made of metal. This is the model I am using:

https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07QFJ6TBG

The only issue I see here is that the microwave might take too long to heat up, but time is not that big of a constraint here.

Comment: Then be sure to set the right mode and you should be good

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a pot of that specific brand, but I've several enamelled cast iron and steel pots and they work fine in my microwave combi oven when used in (convection) oven mode.

Of course you have to make sure that you have the correct mode selected before turning on the oven (do NOT use the combined oven/microwave mode for example), but you should do that regardless of what you put in it.

I've been doing this for over 15 years, never had a problem and the pots nor the oven are any the worse for wear as a result.

Main problem you may have is finding one that's small enough to fit in the oven, as they tend to be rather small compared to dedicated convection